# How to display/allow 'add to cart' for private products in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to prepare b2b woocommerce with custom functions only for registred users. For two days I've been stuck over function that allow add to cart private products. Do any of you have a function that will make it possible?

My capabilities for custom user:

```
array( 'read_private_posts' => true, 'read_private_products' => true
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the actual problem is for your B2B users now? Can't they see the products in the archive or can't they add it to cart (if so, is there any error)?

Comment: They currently see the products but instead of 'add to cart' they only see 'read more'

Comment: If the button add to cart is located in the products loop the "problem" is variable products. Variable products in the products loop will show a read more button because you have to choose the product attribute before you can add it to the cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is still looking for an answer, I have found a solution. It's not perfect because you need to work on additional security. In my case, it helped a lot. Custom users need this capabilities:

```
'read_private_pages' => true,
'read_private_posts' => true,
'read_private_products' => true,
'edit_others_products' => true,
'edit_private_products' => true
```