# WooCommerce - Add a private item to the cart via 'add_to_cart'

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, private

How can I add a private item from my store to the cart?

```
$product_id = 1234;
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
```

Whenever I try to do this, the item is not being added (unless I make it public). I don't want to make it public however since I want to keep these items hidden.

I have found this example after doing a search, but it doesn't explain how to actually implement it. [How to display/allow 'add to cart' for private products in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63055846/2943403)

Comment: [How to assign capabilities to user NOT to User Role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/60433)

Comment: Instead of making the product private, you should set the Catalog visibility to "hidden" and restrict/allow access to the related single product page at the user level… This way you can always add the product to cart programmatically…

Comment: How is it possible to restrict access at the user level when no one is logged in. We're talking about public users here. I want to block access to public users but using my PHP code, add the item to their cart when I decide to.

Comment: I don't see why I can't just make the item private and then forcefully add it using PHP. That would be so much easier. Do you know of a way that I can do such a thing?

Comment: So if you set the Catalog visibility to "hidden", the product will be hidden to users allowing you to add it programmatically to cart…

Comment: But public users who do some snooping on the site can still find the product and add it to their cart and then purchase it. Changing the catalogue to "hidden" is not a viable solution.

Comment: See in [this answer code *(the 3rd function)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64108695/hide-auto-added-gift-product-from-woocommerce-catalog/64109237#64109237) that allows to redirect users trying to access a specific product… So with it, public users who do some snooping on the site will not be able to add it to the cart… then changing the catalogue to "hidden" is a viable solution.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have solved the issue. I've since updated the OP with the reflected changes.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec sure, I have done that now for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Redirect to the WooCommerce 'shop' page if the product is viewed directly

```
// redirect if the product is viewed directly
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_shop');
function redirect_to_shop()
{
    $product_id = 1234;
    
    if (get_the_id() == $product_id)
    {
        wp_redirect(wc_get_page_permalink('shop'));

        exit;
    }
}
```